# Emails from Users

Tags: ios, iphone, email, mobile-website

I am developing an app. One thing that I am working on is getting emails from users for complaints or suggestions. I implemented the code below. When user clicks a button, this leads to an iphone built in email. But user can change the "myappemail" and the title, which I don't want. Also, I feel this may not be safe in terms of security.

So my questions are:
a. Is it safe?
b. Is there any way to prevent user from changing the email and title?
c. If this way is not recommended, An alternative may be using a website. I have a website for my app using Google Suite (free version), but I am not sure that Google Suite provides such "getting email from users" service. If not, how do company generally deal with this? Is there any recommended website building service which provides such service.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks,

```
    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("Mail services are not available")
        return
    } else {
    let sendingEmailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    sendingEmailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
     
    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    sendingEmailVC.setToRecipients(["myappemail@myappemail.com"])
    sendingEmailVC.setSubject("my app - \(userFirstName!) \(userLastName!)")
    sendingEmailVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

    self.present(sendingEmailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
  
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
        didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You can't prevent the user from changing the subject and destination of the email, but why would such a change be unsafe? The worst that would happen is that their email would not get to you if they changed the destination email address.    You could use another service, but recommending such things is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, Paul....! Ok. I just wondered if that is safe. It sounds safe. Yes. I want to prevent the worst case :)

Comment: @matt Yes, if I can prevent the worst case that Paul mentioned about.  By the way, why is this weed? Lol.